# Programmatically update remote video thumbnail

Tags: 8, media

**Scenario:** YouTube video was previously unlisted, so thumbnail not retrieved and now needs to be, or chosen thumbnail has been changed and needs updating.

There are a couple of core issues open on this - see below (e.g. adding an 'Update Metadata' button to the *Media* view), but they're dependent on other open issues such as batch API/bulk operations and neither is at all close to completion.

In the meantime, is there a simple way to do it in code, given [updateThumbnail()](https://github.com/drupal/drupal/blob/8.8.x/core/modules/media/src/Entity/Media.php#L156) is a protected method?

[#2983456 - Expose triggering update of media metadata + thumbnail to end users](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2983456)

[#2878119 - Whether queued or not, update the media thumbnail and metadata before beginning the entity save database transaction](https://www.drupal.org/node/2878119)

Comment: Maybe you missed `public function updateQueuedThumbnail()` in the same class?

Comment: @Clive thanks - yes I completely missed that…

Comment: @WilliamTurrell did you manage to do that ? If so can you post your solution because it does not update with updateThumbnail() on my side? I'm on Drupal 9.3 for info.

Comment: @pbonnefoi can't find it in my code anymore, I might have run it by hand in shell… The use in core is ``$media->updateQueuedThumbnail();`` followed by ``$media->save();``

Comment: Well I tried that but got the original thumbnail. I was trying to replace it by another image from a custom field in Remote Video entity